# How to store N number of values on a column header?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

i have the following jsfiddle to generate a jqgrid in pivot. [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/e1rvyczh/1/)
it uses the following json data.

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    "fuelusagecity": "17",
    "fuelusagehwy": "12",
    "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 120000.0000,
    "highsalestext": null,
    "salesdate": "2010-12-01", 
    "shortsalesdate": "10-12-01", 
    "groupheaderorder":"1",
    "childorder":"1"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    "fuelusagecity": "10",
    "fuelusagehwy": "14",
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
    "totalnumberofsales": 100000.0000,
    "highsalestext": "HIGH",
    "salesdate": "2010-12-15",
    "shortsalesdate": "10-12-15", 
    "groupheaderorder":"1",
    "childorder":"1"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "belta",
    "fuelusagecity": "15",
    "fuelusagehwy": "10",
    "salesaboveavg": true,
    "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
    "totalnumberofsales": 200000.0000,
    "highsalestext": null,
    "salesdate": "2011-01-10",
    "shortsalesdate": "11-01-10", 
    "groupheaderorder":"1",
    "childorder":"2"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "camry",
    "fuelusagecity": "13",
    "fuelusagehwy": "10",
    "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 300000.0000,
    "highsalestext": "HIGH",
    "salesdate": "2011-04-23",
    "shortsalesdate": "11-04-23",
    "groupheaderorder":"1",
    "childorder":"3"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "make": "nissan",
    "model": "skyline",
    "fuelusagecity": "14",
    "fuelusagehwy": "9",
    "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
    "salesaboveavg": true,
    "totalnumberofsales": 500000.0000,
    "highsalestext": "HIGH",
    "salesdate": "2010-09-10",
    "shortsalesdate": "10-09-10",
    "groupheaderorder":"2",
    "childorder":"1"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "make": "nissan",
    "model": "zx300",
    "fuelusagecity": "10",
    "fuelusagehwy": "8",
    "fuelmeasure":'Litre',
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 400000.0000,
    "highsalestext": null,
    "salesdate": "2012-01-06",
    "shortsalesdate": "12-01-06",
    "groupheaderorder":"2",
    "childorder":"2"
}];
```

in the json data, **sales date** comes in two formats `salesdate` property has the year in four digits and the `shortsalesdate` has the year in two digits. On the grid dynamic sales dates columns must display sales date in the format yy-mm-dd (so to display it should use `shortsalesdate` property).

In the fiddle code dates were sorted in the descending order. the new modification also must sort the dates in the decendding order. This time it should use the sales date in the property `salesdate` for sorting but it should display the sales date using the property 'shortsalesdate` on the column header.

Secondly, there are two button to show and hide columns. there is a comparison of sales dates in the method `getYColumnName` before hiding/showing. In the current jsfiddle code it uses the value in the `salesdate` property to compare. this should be kept as it is.

So there are basically two things: 
1. To display of the sales dates, it should use the value in the property `shortsalesdate`
2. for all dates comparisons and sorting it must use the value in property `salesdate`

How do i achieve this?

**side note:** 
i was thinking about storing two values in the column header one hidden value from property `shortsalesdate` and one visible value from property `shortsalesdate`. So basically is it possible to store two values in a column?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest you some workaround how you could implement your requirements in the current version 4.13.6 of free jqGrid, but I think that solution of your problem should be very easy.

What you want to do is just customizing of the text, which will be displayed in the column header. Thus I made some changes in the code of free jqGrid (see here) and posted the results to GitHub.

[The demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/e1rvyczh/4/) loads the latest code from GitHub and it uses

```js
yDimension: [
    { dataName: "salesdate", sortorder: "desc",
        label: function (options) {
            // options has the following properties:
            //    yData, yIndex, yLevel, pivotOptions
            var date = String(options.yData).split("-");
            return date[0].substr(2) + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[2];
        }}
]
```

The new `label` callback allows to construct the column header based on the data. I split the date by `-`, cut the first two symbols from the year and build new string. One see the results like on the picture below

[image]

My demo don't use `shortsalesdate` property and just uses the original `salesdate`.

The same works in case of usage multiple elements in `yDimension`. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/e1rvyczh/3/ uses

```js
yDimension: [
    { dataName: "salesYear", sorttype: "integer", sortorder: "desc",
        label: function (options) {
            return "(" + options.yData + ")";
        }},
    { dataName: "salesdate", sortorder: "desc",
        label: function (options) {
            // options has the following properties:
            //    yData, yIndex, yLevel, pivotOptions
            var date = String(options.yData).split("-");
            return date[0].substr(2) + "-" + date[1] + "-" + date[2];
        }}
]
```

with dummy formatting for the year: I just enclose it in braces: `(` and `)` using `return "(" + options.yData + ")";`. The results looks as following

[image]

It's important that you refresh your sources of free jqGrid from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/archive/master.zip))